# Send value from view to ActionResult controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass value of < li > element from one partial view to ActionResult in controller and update second partial view with filtered result on the base of chosen < li > value.

My problem is that right now I am not able to pass the value to the controller.

This is my code in the first view from which I want to set the filter:

```
@if (MainFaqCategories != null && MainFaqCategories != null && MainFaqCategories.Count != 0)
    {<ul class="faq-menu">
            @foreach (var mainType in MainFaqCategories)
            {
                <li id="@mainType.TabCode" onclick="getChosenCategory(this.id)">@mainType.Descr</li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
```

This is my Ajax code:

```
var lang = $("html").attr("lang");
function getChosenCategory(selectedCategory) {
    console.log(selectedCategory);
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetChosenFaqSubCategory")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: { TypeCode: selectedCategory},
    });
}
```

This is my code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetChosenFaqSubCategory(string TypeCode)
    {
        string pFilter = "WebFaqCategoryCd=" + TypeCode;
        int maxnr = Convert.ToInt32(MaxNbrFaq);

        List<ArticleFAQ> subCategories = ServiceWrapper.GetWebFaq(pCoCd, language, loginId, pFilter, out maxnr, out errorText);

        return PartialView("GlobalFAQ", subCategories);
    }
```

As an error I have in the console: 
POST - http://localhost:4361/en/FAQ/GetChosenFaqSubCategory - 404 (Not Found)

When I remove the language part then other controller is throwing error because the site has multiple languages and I need it

Comment: What error do you have ? did you check developer tools of your browser?

Comment: As an error I have in the console:
POST http://localhost:4361/en/faq/GetChosenFaqSubCategory?TypeCode=20 - 404 (Not Found).
When I remove the language part then other controller is throwing error because the site has multiple languages and I need it

Comment: What is your controller name?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a controller to url

```
//@Url.Action("Action","Controller")
 var url = '@Url.Action("GetChosenFaqSubCategory","...your controller")';
```

and remove Post from the action, and add routing, since you use lang, it is very confusing

```
 [Route("~/{ln}/faq/GetChosenFaqSubCategory")]
 public ActionResult GetChosenFaqSubCategory(string ln,string typeCode)
```

if it still is not working, try to use get

```
 [Route("~/{ln}/faq/GetChosenFaqSubCategory/{typeCode}")]
 public ActionResult GetChosenFaqSubCategory(string ln,string typeCode)
```

and ajax

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("GetChosenFaqSubCategory","...your controller")';

    $.ajax({
        url: url+"/"+selectedCategory,
        type: 'GET',
        success: ...  your partial view code
          });
```

Comment: That's not the reason. It is finding the controller properly. I added to the question what error is showing in the console

Comment: @Atanas , I don't know how you config your routing, so try the attribute routing in my answer and post your endpoints configuration from startup too.